# Next JS - API Routes - Exception handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I have the following form(client) component in my next js app:

```
"use client"
type FormData = {
    email: string
}

const schema = object({
    email: string().email().required("Please enter your email."),
})
const ForgotPasswordForm = () => {
    const {executeRecaptcha} = useGoogleReCaptcha()
    const {toast} = useToast()

    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        reset,
        formState: {errors},
    } = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    })

    const submitData = async (data: FormData) => {
        if (!executeRecaptcha) {
            return
        }
        const token = await executeRecaptcha("onSubmit")
        const formData = {...data, token}
        mutate(formData)
    }

    const {isLoading: loading, mutate} = useMutation<any, any, any>(
        {
            mutationFn: async (data) => {
                return await axios.post("/api/forgot-password", data)
            },
            onSuccess: (data:any) => {
                console.log("data",data)
                toast({
                    title: "Success",
                    variant: 'default',
                    description: "Password reset link email sent successfully.",
                })
                reset()
            },
        }
    )


 return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitData)}>
                <div className="formRow mb-[10px]">
                    <Input label="Email" placeholder="Email" id="email" type="email"
                           error={errors.email ? errors.email.message : null}
                           {...register("email")}/>
                </div>
                <Button additionalClass="w-full !font-normal" submit loading={loading}>
                    Send Reset Password Link
                </Button>
            </form>
       )
}
export {ForgotPasswordForm}
```

My api code to handle the form request

```
import API from "@/lib/axios"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

export async function POST(req: Request, response: Response) {
    try {
        const {  email } = await req.json()
        
        const res = await API.post("/forgot-password", {
            email,
        })

        return NextResponse.json({
            message: res.data.message,
            status: res.status,
        })
    } catch (e) {
        throw e
    }
}
```

In the above code API is my axios instance. Using it i'm sending request to my laravel api server that sends the email to user.

When user is not found with given email i get the following response from the server

`data: { success: false, message: 'User is not registered.' }`

But with the above code i'm getting error in by frontend console:

**AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config:.....}**

I want to display the error message sent by laravel backend in frontend.

Although i'm forwarding the same message that i get from the laravel backend i'm not able to show in the frontend.

I would be thankful if anyone could point out mistakes I've made here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please check the HTTP code received from the response given by Laravel Server.**

- You may use a API Testing tool or just `console.log(res)` the response & see the
  HTTP code.
- Also `log the error object e`, to get more details
- If HTTP code is in range of 500s its an error from server side. If server has attached error code with this message then axios will consider it as error.

*Read about Error Codes : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status*

**You should return a response under your catch statement.**

As you have wrote `throw e` it won't send any response to the frontend.

Try updating your catch code with this & check :
*(Before this log e object & then populate below fields)*

```
catch (e) {
       return NextResponse.json({
            "success": res.data.success,
            "message": res.data.message,
            "status": res.status, //log e & then set
            "error" : e  //log e & then set
        })
}
```